# How to find building specs & blueprint(s) for an apartment complex?

Tags: building-design, architecture, specifications, documentation

For any given apartment complex in the U.S. (if you want to get specific, I am wondering about NYC), how does one track down the building's specifications. I'm talking about specs as detailed as the thickness of the walls (this is really the detail I care about).

I assume one would first have to know what company built the complex, and then one would have to consult some database of theirs for the specs. I am not sure though. How does one go about finding out something like this?

Comment: Owner? Planning office? Or don't you know either? Google may help.

Comment: I'm asking this for research for a book, so the building is fictional, in case that's relevant. How might I find out who the owner of the building is? @SolarMike

Comment: You decide: Sirius Cybernetics Corporation, Weyland etc

Comment: @SolarMike Yeah, that's the gift of being God xD However, let's say the owner is one of those; how would my character figure that out, and where would they go from there in order to figure out the wall thickness?